# Unable To Install Windows KB

Tags: windows, dism

I am trying to install KB4592440 and it keeps failing.  Since the user is remote ... I ran:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
```

1. And I found this bad reg key:

   ```
   (p)  CBS Registry Error  0x8007000d      amd64_microsoft.windows.c..-controls.resources_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.0.0_sv-se_ef79f25f2c83ab1a
   ```
2. So I Reg Query the key and I deleted it:

   ````
   r6QIa b11434_for_KB4551853~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.7.4551853-2056_neutral    REG_NONE    35002E00380032002E00310037003700360033002E003100320031003700400032000000```
   ````
3. Ran KB4592440 again and it failed.  So I ran DISM again.
4. Opened up CBS.log and found these errors:

   ```
    2020-12-30 11:00:56, Error                 CSI    00000007 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #151875# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysOpenKey(flg = (AllowAccessDenied), key = {provider=NULL, handle=0, name= ("null")}, da = (KEY_READ|KEY_WOW64_64KEY), oa = @0xb781a7ada8->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[216]'\Registry\Machine\COMPONENTS\DerivedData\VersionedIndex\10.0.17763.1574 (WinBuild.160101.0800)\ComponentFamilies\amd64_microsoft.windows.c..-controls.resources_6595b64144ccf1df_ar-sa_0faf2111d4a10a95\v!6.0.17763.[gle=0xd0000034]
    2020-12-30 11:00:56, Error                 CSI    1282'; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, disp = Unmapped disposition: 2175249288)[gle=0xd0000034]
    2020-12-30 11:00:56, Error                 CSI    00000008@2020/12/30:16:00:56.382 (F) onecore\base\wcp\sil\ntsystem.cpp(5348): Error STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND originated in function Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysOpenKey expression: (null)
    [gle=0x80004005]
    2020-12-30 11:00:56, Error                 CSI    00000009 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #151874# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysOpenKey(flg = 0, key = {provider=NULL, handle=0, name= ("null")}, da = (KEY_READ|KEY_WOW64_64KEY), oa = @0xb781a7ada8->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[216]'\Registry\Machine\COMPONENTS\DerivedData\VersionedIndex\10.0.17763.1574 (WinBuild.160101.0800)\ComponentFamilies\amd64_microsoft.windows.c..-controls.resources_6595b64144ccf1df_ar-sa_0faf2111d4a10a95\v!6.0.17763.1282'; a:(OBJ_CASE[gle=0xd0000034]
    2020-12-30 11:00:56, Error                 CSI    _INSENSITIVE)}, disp = Unmapped disposition: 2175250284)[gle=0xd0000034]
    2020-12-30 11:00:56, Error                 CSI    0000000a@2020/12/30:16:00:56.701 (F) onecore\base\wcp\sil\ntsystem.cpp(5348): Error STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND originated in function Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysOpenKey expression: (null)
    [gle=0x80004005]
    2020-12-30 11:00:56, Error                 CSI    0000000b (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #151873# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CBufferedRegistryProvider::SysOpenKey(flg = 0, key = {provider=NULL, handle=0, name= ("null")}, da = (KEY_ALL_ACCESS), oa = @0xb781a7b308->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[216]'\Registry\Machine\COMPONENTS\DerivedData\VersionedIndex\10.0.17763.1574 (WinBuild.160101.0800)\ComponentFamilies\amd64_microsoft.windows.c..-controls.resources_6595b64144ccf1df_ar-sa_0faf2111d4a10a95\v!6.0.17763.1282'; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENS[gle=0xd0000034]
    2020-12-30 11:00:56, Error                 CSI    ITIVE)}, disp = Unmapped disposition: 2175251296)[gle=0xd0000034]
    2020-12-30 11:00:56, Error                 CSI    0000000c (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #151872# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CKey::OpenExistingKey(f = 2, da = (KEY_ALL_ACCESS), oa = @0xb781a7b590, key = NULL, disp = (null))[gle=0xd0000034]
    2020-12-30 11:00:56, Error                 CSI    0000000d (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #251# from CCSDirect::EnumStoreCorruptions(...)[gle=0xd0000034]
    2020-12-30 11:00:56, Error                 CSI    0000000e (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) #250# from Windows::COM::CStorePendingStoreRepairTxn_IStorePendingStoreRepairTransaction::Detect(Flags = 4, cancelEvt = 4f8 (''), disp = 0)[gle=0x80070002]
    2020-12-30 11:00:56, Error                 CBS    Rept: Failed to call CSI detect. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
   ```
5. I am a little over my head here ... I want know what to do?  Is there a way to repair the last KB install for the language AR-SA?  I have tried `sfc /scannow`

Can someone help?

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Comment: This KB is for Windows 10 version 1809. Are you still on that version? If you are on a later version then you already have it. Why do you want to install this specific KB?

Comment: Run `winver` to get the Windows version number. Also, you might explain what you see message wise when it fails too.

Comment: Why are you trying to install an update released in May 2020?  Even in the case of 1809 there a newer updates, like [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4592440) for example, without Windows Update logs we won’t be able to diagnose the problem

Answer (score -1):

We could try the following steps to install update.

1.Create a new folder named as C:\temp\cab
2.Download update package from http://catalog.update.microsoft.com to C:\temp
3.Run command line below to exact .msu file for getting .cab file.
**expand -F:* C:\temp{.msu file name with extension} C:\temp\cab**
4.Run DISM command line below to add .cab file.
**Dism /online /add-package /packagepath:c:\temp\cab{.cab file with extension}**

By the way, your log file is not a whole file, so might be not provide a full info for debug.

Comment: I ran your requested command, it got to 75% and failed:
Dism /online /add-package /packagepath:c:\temp\Windows10.0-KB4592440-x64_PSFX.cab

This is the DISM.Log file:

Comment: CBS log is necessary to debug this issue, it located on C:\Windows\logs\cbs\cbs.log